# How to install Ubuntu 11.04's system settings in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, system-settings

I loved how System Settings (or Control Center) looked back in Ubuntu 11.04.

[image]

The System settings in 11.10 looks like the one in OSX, which I don't like it.

How can I have it in Ubuntu 12.04?  Or is there any Third-Party System Settings that has the same functionality or look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can't do it without hacking

Because system settings in the 11.04 is the system settings for the GNOME 2, and system settings in the 12.04 is system settings for the GNOME 3. Still you may can compile it from source (It may break your system). But it is out of the scope of my answer.

Edit:

Installing MATE desktop in ubuntu will give classic system settings.

Comment: I would rather hack

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but a partial one. The User Account Settings can be made available for 12.04 by installing gnome-system-tools.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

it will bring back the **Users and Group Settings** (not is system settings though)