# old application launcher window in the repository

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, launcher, repository, .desktop

In older version of Ubuntu there used to be (in the repository) an application launcher window, that itself was a normal gtk application.

It was just like the old control-center mentioned in [How to install Ubuntu 11.04's system settings in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151930/how-to-install-ubuntu-11-04s-system-settings-in-ubuntu-12-04), probably sharing most of their codebase, but displaying only entries for those `.desktop` files which are apps not settings.

What is/was it called?

Is it (or some equivalent fork/rename) in the current (14.04) repo?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any applications *specifically designed* to do this with the layout that you describe, but Whisker Menu has this layout.

Whisker Menu is a plugin for Xfce that gives the user a nicer menu, and appears when it's clicked on the panel.

However, if you're desperate, you can run it inside Unity with some hacks - open up a terminal and do the following:

1. Install xfce4-panel: `sudo apt-get install xfce4-panel`
2. Install Whisker Menu: `sudo apt-get install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin`
3. Run Xfce panel by pressing Alt F2 and typing `xfce4-panel`
4. Choose to create one empty panel if asked.
5. Right-click and go to panel preferences.
6. Resize it to the size you want and click 'items'.
7. Add Whisker Menu to the panel by clicking the 'Add' button and choosing it.
8. Close the preferences and done - now you have a panel with Whisker Menu!

Comment: there actually was such in the 10.04 or 12.04 repositories, I used to use it, but forgot its name

Comment: So I must have a panel to use it? Otherwise it would be great.

Comment: Yeah I've looked around but it seems that you can't easily run it on its own.

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/q/463997/363110